# Programatically run console app either as foreground or background process c#

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I have a console application that i would be scheduling to run via Windows Task Scheduler. Now one of my requirements is to have it run either as foreground or background process based on app.config setting. Is it possible to achieve?

Comment: Does it have to be a console application?

Comment: This is configured in Task Scheduler, not your .config file.  It determines what user account and session are used to run your program, not your config file.

Comment: Yeah, but on production server, nobody would want to change the task.

Comment: A console application will run the console window pretty much regardless of what you do, while WinForms will only run the form if told to do so. Combine Alfie's and Anthony's solutions and put the code in the application startup to make it start a new instance of itself if to be run without a window, then make it terminate the current instance. That way you can control the behaviour without using two applications.

Comment: @VisualVincent The last sentence of your comment confuses me. Two applications?

Comment: @AnthonyGuertin : _"**without** using two applications"_, meaning you **don't need** two applications.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a console application in the **background** through code by using this code

```
string path = "C:\\myfile.bat";
string args = "";
ProcessStartInfo procInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(path, args);
procInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
procInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
procInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
Process procRun = Process.Start(procInfo);
procRun.WaitForExit();
```

To run this in the foreground change the `WindowStyle` line to

```
procInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
```

Comment: But wouldn't this mean i have to create another console app which calls the main console app? Ideally i would want this be a single app which has a check based on app setting key to either run the main method as frontend or background process.

Answer (score 1):

### --- EDIT ---

I just remembered, you could just use the Windows API to hide the window.

You will require these namespaces:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

Then you can import these two functions:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, uint nCmdShow);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();
```

`GetConsoleWindow()` will get the window handle to the current console window.

`ShowWindow()` is a WinAPI function that lets you show/hide/minimize/maximize/etc. windows by sending their window handles to it.

In your `Main()` method you can now just do like this whenever the `-silent` argument is passed:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length >= 1 && args.Any(s => s.Equals("-silent", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))) //Case-insensitively iterate through all arguments and look for the arg "-silent".
    {
        ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), 0); //0 is equal to SW_HIDE, which means hide the window.
    }
}
```

So in the Task Scheduler, just make it start your application with the argument `-silent`, and it shouldn't display the window.

Hope this helps!

---

### --- Old answer ---

In order to be able to start your application as a foreground/background application without the aid of a second application you must have some way of indicating to your app that you want it to start without a window.

Once your application starts, you could make it check for a certain argument that tells wether you want it to be in the background or not. Then you could make your application start a new instance of itself without no window, automatically closing the current instance afterwards.

Using `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` you are able to obtain the name and full path of the current executable via the `CodeBase` property. You can then just pass that along to an instance of the `ProcessStartInfo` class with the proper settings to not create a window.

This is an example of a `Main()` method doing so:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length >= 1 && args.Any(s => s.Equals("-silent", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))) //Case-insensitively iterate through all arguments and look for the arg "-silent".
    {
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase); //Start this application again.
        psi.CreateNoWindow = true; //Create no window (make it run in the background).
        psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; //Create no window (make it run in the background).
        psi.WorkingDirectory = Process.GetCurrentProcess().StartInfo.WorkingDirectory; //Use the same working directory as this process.

        Process.Start(psi); //Start the process.
        return; //Stop execution, thus stopping the current process.
    }

//...your normal code here...
}
```

Note that this code **must** be on the ***very top*** of your `Main()` method.

The only problem with this code is that in order to close the application (if it doesn't close itself) you must forcibly kill the process either via the task manager or a second application (yes, sadly).

```
foreach (Process myApp in Process.GetProcessesByName("myApplication")) //Your executable's name, without the ".exe" part.
{
    myApp.Kill();
}
```

The new instance is also not in control by the Task Scheduler, meaning you cannot stop it from there either.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly a "task" but could be references as one. Right click on your project and go to properties. Inside of properties there should be an option inside of Application Tab -> Output type -> [switch it to "Windows Application"]:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestConsoleApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        private const string GuiWinForm = "gui";
        private const string GuiConsole = "console";
        private const string BackgroundProcess = "bgp";
        private const string Cmd = "cmd";

        [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool AttachConsole(int dwProcessId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out int lpdwProcessId);

        private static void LoadForm()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();

            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool AllocConsole();

        private static void CreateNewConsole()
        {
            AllocConsole();
            Console.WriteLine("New Console App");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void LoadConsole()
        {
            // *** Gets Command Window if it is already open ***
            var ptr = GetForegroundWindow();
            int u;

            GetWindowThreadProcessId(ptr, out u);

            var process = Process.GetProcessById(u);

            if (process.ProcessName == Cmd)
                AttachConsole(process.Id);
            // *** Creates a new Command Prompt if the foreground is not a console ***
            else
                CreateNewConsole();
        }

        // Get the args from either command line or from config file
        [STAThread]
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var mode = args.Length > 0 ? args[0] : Gui;

            switch (mode)
            {
                case Gui:
                    LoadForm();
                    break;
                /* If for some reason you just cannot stand the 
                idea of using a winform for this task/process */
                case GuiConsole:
                     LoadConsole();
                     break;
                case BackgroundProcess:
                    // Code that will perform task
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```